# Need help getting intel TBB working?

Tags: c++, c++11, tbb

I ran brew install tbb on my mac os sierra device. After running this i should be able to include #include into my c++ projects right? For some reason when I compile these files are not found. Help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. I wrote a concurrent queue implementation for my own application and want to test it against intel tbb's concurrent queue. I use OS X sierra. I simply installed homebrew and then ran 'brew install tbb' in terminal. I assume this sets all the environment variables and what not? Then when i try to access the concurrent_queue.h header through the include statement i get the error: /Users/irtazasafi/ClionProjects/as2/main.cpp:7:9: fatal error: 'concurrent_queue.h' file not found

Comment: I tried both. When i try <tbb/concurrent_queue.h> it still cannot find the file. Brew says it's already installed (tbb-4.4-20160916 already installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things...

#### Check the options on packages

Before you install any `homebrew` packages, get in the habit of checking the available options rather than just accepting the default ones. It often gives you insights into features that are available which you are unaware of. So, for `tbb`:

```
brew options tbb
```

**Output**

```
--c++11
    Build using C++11 mode
```

So, it is probably worth using:

```
brew install tbb --c++11
```

or

```
brew reinstall tbb --c++11
```

### Find the include files and libraries yourself first

If you are trying to include a header file, try looking for it yourself first, using `find`:

```
find /usr /opt concurrent_queue.h
```

**Output**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/4.4-20160916/include/tbb/concurrent_queue.h
```

So there is only one `concurrent_queue.h` on my system. Now we need to tell the compiler how to find it. If you look in `/usr/local/include`, which is where `homebrew` puts headers, you will see this:

```
ls -l /usr/local/include | grep tbb
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    38  5 Oct 09:10 tbb -> ../Cellar/tbb/4.4-20160916/include/tbb
```

So, the `tbb` headers are in `/usr/local/include/tbb` (which is a symlink to `homebrew`'s Cellar), so you need to make sure your compiler is looking in `/usr/local/include`.

```
g++-6 -I/usr/local/include ...
```

Remember you can check where your compiler is looking by using `-v`, like this:

```
g++-6 -v ...
```

Once you helped the compiler find the header files (#includes), you will then need to help the linker find the libraries, so your command will become:

```
g++-6 -I/usr/local/include program.cpp -o program -L /usr/local/lib -ltbb
```

Comment: find /usr /opt concurrent_queue.h says I have no concurrent_queue.h on my disk.

Comment: Irtazas-MacBook-Pro:~ irtazasafi$ brew install tbb --c++11
Warning: tbb-4.4-20160916 already installed

Comment: Sorry, I meant `find /usr -name concurrent_queue.h`

Comment: g++ std=c++11 main.cpp

When I try and do g++-6 -I/usr/local/include ... i get the error : -bash: g++-6: command not found

Comment: Have you installed `gcc` with `brew install gcc`?

Comment: No. I have the developer tools that come with Xcode. The find command does return the exact same location as you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: So, if you are using `g++`, try `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -I /usr/local/include -o main -ltbb`

Comment: ld: library not found for -ltbb

Comment: Cool - we are nearly there! Just add `-L /usr/local/lib`

Comment: thank you. Haven't used c++ for ages so come across as a dumbass :p

Comment: No problems - I'm glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project and come back and ask more questions if you get stuck - answers are free